# Boto3 is installed but cannot find module RHEL 7

Tags: python, pip, rhel7

I'm trying to get the AWS-CLI working to start and configure ec2 instances.

I've installed boto3 through pip, pip3 and python install but still can't see boto3.

```
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

I'm running RHEL 7. I've tried several different ways of installing it,

```
pip install boto3
pip3 install boto3
python3 -m pip install --user boto3
```

The first time I ran `pip install boto3` it went through the installation output, as it did with `pip3 install boto3` but now it just says `requirement already satisfied`, as it is already installed.

I've installed `rh-python36-python-pip` then `scl enable rh-python36 bash` to get pip working, which is working fine.

I've googled and googled and can't find any other answers, since it appears to be installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the CentOS 7 python-boto3 package from the CentOS repo, and it worked first time.

*http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/aarch64/Packages/python-boto3-1.4.6-5.el7.noarch.rpm*